# Pandora is choppy when using a volume booster

Tags: google-chrome, audio, pandora

Some of the computers I listen to Pandora on have rather wimpy sound, even with Pandora's volume slider turned up to max, and the earbuds I'm using don't have any built-in volume control, so I've tried using a volume-booster extension to remedy this; unfortunately, they all appear to make Pandora go choppy when I turn them on.  The browser I'm using is Google Chrome.

Why does using a volume booster make Pandora go choppy, and what can I do to fix this?

EDIT: I've tried two, both of them Chrome extensions: one of them is [Volume Booster](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-booster/ejkiikneibegknkgimmihdpcbcedgmpo), and the other seems to have disappeared from the Chrome Web Store since yesterday.

Comment: Is the volume booster a piece of software or hardware? Can you show us what it looks like or link to the volume booster?

Comment: Just a guess, but may be the plugin takes long enough to reprocess the audio (or there is some other technical issues in implementation) it's simply interferes with the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [volumebooster.io](https://volumebooster.io/) chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-booster-plus/ofljijikiakjkfjjhkmalhcjdhndcofl?hl=en&authuser=0

I have been using this extension from last few months. It working fine for me.